# xml de-serialization related problem occur

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

suppose i have xml data stored in string variable. so when i am trying to de-serialize xml to my class then i am getting error for property name.

```
  [XmlAttribute("Name")]
  public string CompanyName
  {
    get
    {
      return __CompanyName;
    }
    set
    {
      if (value != null)
        __CompanyName = value;
      else
        __CompanyName = "";
    }
  }
```

actually i am getting error because in my xml there is Name tag but in my code the property name is CompanyName. that is why i am getting error. is there any way to map the property in my property as a result Name will be mapped with CompanyName and no problem occur during deserialization. please help. [XmlAttribute("Name")]... it should be xmlelement instead of XmlAttribute. need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the name is fine; you just need the right attributes. You don't show the XML, but it looks like you just need

```
[XmlElement("Name")]
public string CompanyName {...etc...}
```

If the type is outside your control, you can use `XmlAttributeOverrides` to re-educate `XmlSerializer` - but if you do that you ***must*** cache and re-use the serializer instance (or you will leak memory).

Comment: please tell me how name in xml data will automatically will be stored in companyname. what i need to do for mapping when i will de-serialize it.

Comment: @user728750 the `[XmlElement("Name")]` is what tells it to map the `CompanyName` property to the `<Name>blah</Name>` element. Nothing else is required. If that isn't doing the job, please show example xml.